# Retrieving the indexes of all items containing a value

Tags: java

I need to get all the index numbers were in i will get a match of the keyword 'Articles' & also i want the counter 'indexoccurencecounter' to increment only if i get a match.

```
List<String> valueslist = new ArrayList<String>();
valueslist.add("Articles");
valueslist.add("Vals");
valueslist.add("Articles");
valueslist.add("Toast");

String key="Articles";

System.out.println("List contents having values are: "+valueslist);
int ind=0;
int indexoccurencecounter=0;
for (int i=0;i<valueslist.size();i++){
    ind=valueslist.indexOf(key);    
    if (ind>=0){
        indexoccurencecounter++;
    }   
}
System.out.println("Index's of the key "+key+" is: "+ind);
System.out.println("The key specified appears "+indexoccurencecounter+" times in the result links");
```

My above code is giving me incorrect output, i am expecting the output to be like below:

```
List contents having values are: [Articles, Vals, Articles, Toast]
Index's of the key Articles is: 0,2
The key specified appears 2 times in the result links
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because multiple indexes will match, `int ind` cannot keep track of them all. It could only keep track of one. I suggest you create a `List<Integer>` of indices. A useful side-effect of doing that is that you no longer have to count the occurrences—you can simply use the `size()` method of the list.

```java
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add("Articles");
values.add("Vals");
values.add("Articles");
values.add("Toast");

String searchTerm = "Articles";

List<Integer> matchingIndices = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    String candidate = values.get(i);
    if (candidate.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0) {
        matchingIndices.add(i);
    }
}

int numberOfMatches = matchingIndices.size();

System.out.println("Values: " + values);
System.out.println("Indexes of the key '" + searchTerm + "': " + matchingIndices);
System.out.println("The key appears " + numberOfMatches + " times.");
```

Produces:

```
Values: [Articles, Vals, Articles, Toast]
Indexes of the key 'Articles': [0, 2]
The key appears 2 times.
```